# Bison end of File gives syntax error?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

In my yacc file the i have a start symbol 'Program' as:

```
Program: Declaration Statements E_O_F {/*Semantic Action*/};
```

The E_O_F is a token returned by flex-lexer as:

```
<<EOF>> return E_O_F;
```

But when i compile my file, there is always a syntax error being reported at the lastline+1 th line. 
Lex File: [File](http://pastebin.com/4ytPrmjm)
Yacc File: [File](http://pastebin.com/8vdSJnjE)

**Input: test.txt**

```
a=(b);
b=c+d/e;
a=3/5-2*4;
a=a-b;
if(a>b) 
{
    a=a+1;
}
```

I think i am not returning the

```
<<EOF>>
```

token correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to explicitly return an `EOF` token, and your grammar should not attempt to detect `EOF`.

bison/yacc always creates an implicit start rule:

```
real_start: start <<EOF>>
```

where `start` is your start production, and `<<EOF>>` is token type `0`.

Furthermore, `flex` always returns `0` when it finds the end of input.

So those two things work together to make it unnecessary for you to worry about `EOF` in the normal course of events. However, they do complicate life if you want your parser to only parse part of the input (which doesn't seem to be the case in this question).

Answer (score 0):

You should mark your custom EOF token with value 0 in .y file:

```
%token E_O_F 0
```